# Errors for finding unique class values within categorical dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has 4 features.

```
df
A|B|C|D
green|big|1.3|4
```

Now, I am putting all object features (A and B)into a new dataframe:

```
df1=df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns
df1.dtype
Out: type('O')
```

The last step is to feed df1 into a function in order to determine unique values per categorical feature.

```
for feature in df1.columns:
    uniq = np.unique(df1[feature])
    print('{}: {} distinct values -  {}'.format(feature,len(uniq),uniq))
```

**Error** I get is:

> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'columns' when I wanted to get this:

**Expected output**:

```
A: 2 distinct values -  ['green' 'blue']
B: 1 distinct values -  ['big]
```

Comment: You should have a look at [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html)

Comment: You already have set `df1` to the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually did something wrong with the `.select_dtypes` line, you already accessed `.columns`. You should remove that:

```
df1=df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])  # no .columns
```

otherwise, the `df1` is now an `Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')`. We do not want that, since, as the error says, you can not access the `.columns` of an `Index` object.

Note that you can simply call `.unique()` here:

```
for feature in df1.columns:
    uniq = df1[feature].unique()
    print('{}: {} distinct values -  {}'.format(feature,len(uniq),uniq))
```

Comment: @Willen Van Onsem, if I wanted to exclude some object columns, how would I specific this in df1=df.select_dtypes(include=['object']) ?